# How to check the warning in linux service status?

Tags: terminal, debian, services, firestarter

If I do:

`$ sudo service <service_name> status`

outputs:

`[warn] <service_name> is running... ... (warning)`

but it doesn't say what warning it is.
How can I check what warning is about?

If it has any relevance the service is **firestarter**.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep firestarter
```

should show you the warnings